# How does the curved spacetime look on both sides of an infinite massive plate with constant mass density?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, branes

On both sides of a massive plate with constant mass density, the gravitational force is uniform. How does the curved spacetime corresponding to such a uniform field look like? Because the field is uniform, the curved spacetime has to be constant. But how is this possible? For example, the time curvature part of the spacetime curvature is everywhere the same. So the farther you are from the plate, the faster time ticks (just as time ticks a little little bit faster when you are high up in the atmosphere of earth). But how can that be if we go farther and farther from the plate to infinity? After all, the field at infinity is the same as at the surface of the plate.

Maybe it is easier to visualize the curvature of spacetime produced by an infinite massive line in three-dimensional spacetime.

Comment: There's a relativistic analysis of an infinite plate [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath530/kmath530.htm).  I haven't checked it myself.  There's a discussion of Newtonian first.

Comment: Thanks for your reference! I already had the feeling there are difficulties in describing this situation with GR.